# Supress all output in this batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch file which outputs limited info. How do I suppress all output from this batch file? What I'd like to see is after I enter the name of the batch file and hit enter, the next thing that shows up on screen is "C:>".

```
 @ECHO OFF
 SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  (for /f "tokens=1 delims=;" %%A in (C:\ALL.txt) do (
  @echo %%A | find /i "\" 
 if errorlevel 1 (
 DEL "D:\!mypath!%%A"  >> C:\ALL-OUT.txt 2>&1
 ) ELSE (
 set  mypath=%%A
  )))
 @endlocal
```

I think it all boils down to this line which I use to test whether %%A contains backslash:

```
 @echo %%A | find /i "\"
```

I tried adding " 1>null" to the end of the line. It worked to suppress all output. However, it also created a file named "null".

Since "For /f" parses files line by line, I wonder if there is a way to incorporate the echo command in "For /f"?

Comment: Use `nul` instead of `null`.

Comment: what is the content of all.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NUL device is referenced with `nul`, not `null`. `>null` creates a file named `null`.

for your second question: you can redirect the output of a command block with a single redirection (in fact, this is [way faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453678/2152082))

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
(
  for /f "delims=;" %%A in (C:\ALL.txt) do (
    echo %%A | find "\" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
      DEL "D:\!mypath!%%A"
    ) ELSE (
      set  mypath=%%A
    )
  )
) > C:\ALL-OUT.txt 2>&1
endlocal
```