# Editing text file to add "-" 8 characters in

Tags: batch-file, text

I deal with a large text files daily, I need to add a single "-" to each line 8 characters in for instance :

```
ABCDEF DC01 B738
ABCDEF      B787
```

would become

```
ABCDEF -DC01 B738
ABCDEF -     B787
```

How easy is this to do with a batch file?

regards
David

Comment: Read http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html then [edit] your question and share a [mcve] where you stuck in.

Comment: As answer to your question: it is very easy to do this with a Batch file! **`;)`**

Comment: @Stephan:  How do you justify your edits to the question?  You seem to have added additional scenarios that were not in the original question.

Comment: @abelenky: see [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41678290/revisions) - check "side-by-side markdown"

Comment: I see your mark down.  You added a new scenario that did not exist in David's original question.  Why?

Comment: it did exist - but we could not see it because of bad formatting. You can clearly see it with "side-by-side-markdown". I only fixed formatting - there was no change to the data.

Comment: (@abelenky: sorry, that it invalidates your answer -  which was fine for the original formatted question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
  set line=%%a
  set line=!line:~0,7!-!line:~7!
  echo !line!
))>output.txt
```

**Note:** this will remove empty lines and has problems with exclamation marks. (may or may not be a problem; depends on your file content)
It also will eliminate lines that begin with `;` due to default EOL character.
Also, lines are limited to ~8190 bytes max length (Thanks dbenham)

Comment: Why a single redirect to `output.txt`, rather than append each `echo !line!` to `output.txt`?

Comment: because it is [much faster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39453678/2152082) - especially with large files (like the question states).

Comment: I'm also concerned it consumes a lot of memory, assembling all the output in mem.

Comment: well, it doesn't collect all the data in memory before writing it. Instead, it opens the file, writes what is to write (without closing the file) until there is no more data. *Then* the file is closed. (you can check, by typing the file while it's getting written (you may want to add a `timeout -t 1` into the loop to get enough time to do so))

Comment: Another limitation - this will eliminate lines that begin with `;` due to default EOL character. Also, lines are limited to ~8190 bytes max length..

Comment: Hi - this is exactly what I need. thank you, the lines I have wont have exclaimation marks in them so this should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "robust" pure batch solution that preserves `!` and empty lines. But it is still limited to ~8190 max line length, and it is painfully slow for large files. This will not modify lines that have less than 7 characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "file=file.txt"

>"%file%.new" (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^"` "file.txt"') do (
    set "s=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!s:*:=!"
    if not defined s (
      echo(
    ) else if "!s:~7!" equ "" (
      echo(!s!
    else (
      echo(!s:~0,7!-!s:~7!
    )
    endlocal
  )
)
move /y "%file%.new" "%file%" >nul
```

And here is a truly robust and fast solution that uses [JREPL.BAT - a regular text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) that is pure script (batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party executable required. This solution also does not modify lines that have fewer than 7 characters.

From the command line:

```
jrepl "^.{7}" "$&-" /f file.txt /o -
```

From within a batch script

```
call jrepl "^.{7}" "$&-" /f file.txt /o -
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple two-lines Batch-JScript *hybrid* script solution that have all the advantages of JScript language: is fast, robust, manage all special characters and preserve empty lines. Besides, it is simple enough to be understood and then modified for other similar tasks after read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0kbytzc(v=vs.84).aspx). Copy it to a file with .BAT extension.

```
@set @a=0 // & cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < input.txt > output.txt & goto :EOF

WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.Stdin.ReadAll().replace(/^.{7}/gm,"$&-"));
```