# batch - take over only certain columns

Tags: batch-file

Good day,

I would like to shorten the following test.txt file by batch and only transfer certain columns to a new testnew.txt.

test.txt:

```
1;2;3;4;5;
```

testnew.txt:

```
1;3;5;
```

I know I can do this using the following batch code:

```
FOR / F "tokens = 1,2,3,4,5 delims =;" %%a in ("% source%") do echo %%a;%%c;%%e;
```

But how can I save it in my target file now?

Comment: Use redirection, either `1>` or `1>>`.

Comment: Like @Compo said, just add `>> filename.txt` to the end of the echo. `>>` redirects output and appends it to a new line of the file whilst `>` creates a new file and overrides files with the name

Comment: See https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39453678/2152082) ("how to make it faster")

Comment: like so: FOR / F "tokens = 1,2,3,4,5 delims =;" %%a in ("%source%") do echo %%a;%%c;%%e; >>%target%

Comment: Check `for /?` for the correct syntax. Don't try to guess it.